# Posting a member of a list with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Say I have a view with a list of items.  For the list I am using the jquery accordion.  Within each DIV of the accordion I have a Save Changes button, intending to save changes to only that member of the list.  How do I construct the AJAX call to send only that single model to the controller?  The accordion is being filled or repeated with a for loop.  So each item in the loop is Model[I] then fields of that particular model.  Is there a way to send only that model?  I am assigning the ID for each button in the list to the ID of the individual model:

```
<button id="but+@Model[i].ID" onclick="SaveChanges(this);return false;" class="displaybutton" style="font-size:x-small">Save Changes</button>

function SaveChanges(btn) {
   var id = btn.id.substring(4);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: @Model[i]  //does not work because there is no way to pass the "i"
    url: '@Url.Action("SaveChanges")'
  });
}
```

This works great in that I can captured fields for that member of the list and include them in the post.  But I have to pull individual values from each field.  I would rather just send that model.  Is there any way to do this?

I found a way to pass the iteration with this:

```
<button id="but+@Model[i].ID" onclick="SaveChanges(this, @i);return false;" class="displaybutton" style="font-size:x-small">Save Changes</button>
```

Using the "@" before the i and it passes.  Now I need to pick the member of the list.  I am converting the list to JSON with this:

```
list = function () { return @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)) }();
```

But posting that member still doesn't work:

```
function SaveChanges(but, numb) {
    var id = but.id;
    id = id.substring(4);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: { review : list[numb] },
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveMeetingMinutes")',
        success: function (data) {
            var test = data;
            $("#accordion").accordion('option', 'active', false);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

The action has the members but they are empty:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveMeetingMinutes(ReviewsModel review)
    {
        Repository.UpdateReview(review);
        return Json(review);
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the full source code?

Comment: You are missing contentType from your ajax call it would be "application/json" in this case.

Comment: Umm, no, it won't even start the ajax call with that.